# Using Sort Arrays and finding the growth rate in states

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods

I am having trouble figuring out why I am getting a mismatch exception, everything was working fine until I opened it on my computer.  I have to take the census file and read it in, which I did, I found the growth rate, but the only problem seems to be this mismatch exception and I dont understand why there is a mismatch error, please help.
Here is the file example:

```
      Alabama,4447100
      Alaska,626932
      Arizona,5130632
      Arkansas,2673400
```

Here is the program:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File f = new File("census2010.txt");
    File ff = new File("census2000.txt");
    if(!f.exists()) {
        System.out.println( "f does not exist ");
    }
    if(!ff.exists()) {
        System.out.println( "ff does not exist ");
    }
    Scanner infile2010 = new Scanner(f);
    Scanner infile2000 = new Scanner(ff);
    infile2010.useDelimiter("[\t|,|\n|\r]+");
    infile2000.useDelimiter("[\t|,|\n|\r]+");
    final int MAX = 60;
    int[] pop10 = new int[MAX];
    int[] pop00 = new int[MAX];
    String[] statearray10 = new String[MAX];
    String[] statearray00 = new String[MAX];
    double [] growtharray = new double[MAX];
    int fillsize;

    fillsize = fillArrayPop (pop10, statearray10, MAX, infile2010, prw);
    fillsize = fillArrayPop2 (pop00, statearray00, MAX, infile2000, prw); // the mismatch exception occurs here
    growthRate(growtharray, pop10, pop00, fillsize);
    sortarray(growtharray, statearray10, fillsize);
    printarray (growtharray, statearray10, fillsize, prw);


}

public static int fillArrayPop (int[] num, String[] statearray10, int mAX, Scanner infile2010, PrintWriter prw) throws FileNotFoundException{
    int retcnt = 0;
    int pop;
    String astate;
    while(infile2010.hasNext()){
        astate = infile2010.next();
        pop = infile2010.nextInt();
        statearray10[retcnt] = astate;
        num[retcnt] = pop;
        retcnt++;
    }
    return (retcnt);
}



public static int fillArrayPop2 (int[] number, String[] statearray00, int mAX, Scanner infile2000, PrintWriter prw) throws FileNotFoundException{
    int retcounts = 0;
    int pop;
    String state;
    while(infile2000.hasNext()){
        state = infile2000.next();
        pop = infile2000.nextInt(); // the mismatch exception occurs here
            statearray00[retcounts] = state;
            number[retcounts] = pop;
            retcounts++;
    }
    return (retcounts);
}

public static void printarray (double[] growth, String[] state, int fillsize, PrintWriter prw){
    DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
    for (int counts = 0; counts < fillsize ; counts++){
        System.out.println("For the position ["+counts+"] the growth rate for " + state[counts] + " is " +form.format(growth[counts]));
        prw.println("For the position ["+counts+"] the growth rate for " + state[counts] + " is " + form.format(growth[counts]));
    }
    prw.close();
    return;
}

public static void growthRate (double[] percent, int[] pop10, int[] pop00, int fillsize){
    double growthrate = 0.0;
        for(int count = 0; count < fillsize; count ++){
            percent[count] = (double)(pop10[count]-pop00[count])/ pop00[count];

        }

}

public static void sortarray(double[] percent, String[] statearray10, int fillsize) {

    for (int fill = 0; fill < fillsize - 1; fill = fill + 1) {

        for (int compare = fill + 1; compare < fillsize; compare++) {

            if (percent[compare] < percent[fill]) {
                double poptemp = percent[fill];
                percent[fill] = percent[compare];
                percent[compare] = poptemp;

                String statetemp = statearray10[fill];
                statearray10[fill] = statearray10[compare];
                statearray10[compare] = statetemp;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: What error? Are you expecting everyone to compile your code to see what and where the error is? Why don't you just tell us?

Comment: To expand on Johns comment, it's a good idea to post the stack.

Comment: I told you the error, it is Input Mismatch Exception and I marked where the errors were. And I just added an example of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Pescis' Answer says, the exception is saying that the token you are trying to get using `nextInt` is not a valid representation of an `int`.  Either it contains unexpected characters, or it is out of range.

If you showed us the exception's message String, and the **complete stacktrace**, it would be easier to diagnose this.  Without that, we have to resort to guessing.

Guess #1:  there is something bad in the actual input data file that you are reading at that point.

Guess #2:  the way you are setting the delimiters regex is wrong.  Your regex seems to be mixing a character class and alternation in a way that is almost certainly incorrect.  It should be this:

```
  useDelimiter("[\\t,\\n\\r]+");
```

(It is not clear that fixing this will fix the problem ... but your regex is wrong none-the-less.)

---

Comments:

1. You have two methods `fillArrayPop` and `fillArrayPop2` that *seem* to be doing the same thing.  As far as I can tell the only differences are different variable names and other non-consequential stuff.
2. Your approach to "parsing" is ignoring the fact that the files are actually line structured.  I think you should (conceptually) read lines and then split the lines into fields.  What you are currently doing is treating them as a sequence of alternating fields.
3. Ideally, your "parsing" should be more robust.  It should at least attempt to diagnose a mismatch between the expected file format and what you actually read from the file.  (If I was writing this, I would at a minimum try to output the line or line number at which the "badness" was detected.)

Comment: Thank you, all I had to do is delete the file and make a new one!

Answer (score 0):

From the [javadoc of `Scanner.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29):

> InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer
>   regular expression, or is out of range

This means, either the next token you are trying to read when it throws the error can not be parsed as an Integer. This can happen for instance if there are non-numeric letters in the token or if the integer is out of range, i.e smaller than -2,147,483,648 or bigger than 2,147,483,647.

If no token in your file is out of range, it's most likely because the file's layout is not how you are programming it to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you take out your prw in your print array your program should run without error. DELETE prw.println("For the position ["+counts+"] the growth rate for " + state[counts] + " is " + form.format(growth[counts])); and DELETE prw.close() and it should run.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is formatted exactly as you have described above, then the .next() method call immediately above the error is actually pulling the whole line (i.e. the variable "state" would contain "Alabama,4447100").

Since there is no whitespace/delimiter between the state name and population, .next() reads the whole line, and the next call to .nextInt() attempts to read the next line (a string), generating an error.

I would recommend reading each line individually, and then splitting up the two pieces of data by the comma that separates them. Also, why do you pass a method a PrintWriter object, if the object isn't used in the method?